# Delete a git file from branch after commiting

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I used git pull origin master to solve a conflict, now my files have been pulled from my master to my source branch, which is not what I wanted, I tried to delete them directly from Intelij, but my PR looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XagQk.png)

How can I delete the files that I do not want to my PR ?
Thanks

Comment: `git rm`? But then they _will be removed_. In other words: after merging your PR, the files will be gone from the target branch too.

Comment: @knittl , if I use git rm will the files be completely gone from my branch and from my PR?, i need to get rid of the files before merging

Comment: Yes, they will be gone from your branch and your PR and from all future branches. Your branch will contain the change "delete file X Y Z" and this change will propagate to other branches when you merge your branch into them

Answer (score -1):

git rm  should remove the file, but you need to commit the changes

Answer (score -2):

Are the files you don't want from the master source?
Then you can use

```
git reset --hard
```

you can only use

```
git merge --no-ff origin/<branch-name>
```

to get the changes

Comment: Careful, `git reset --hard` will remove ALL uncommitted changes!

Comment: Couldn't pull `git pull` without using the `git push` command due to the existence of conflicting files.